# SAPUI5: OdataModel v2 defaultOperationMode Client does not fetch data initially

Tags: fetch, odata, sapui5

I have a sap.m.tree where I want the data to be fetched once and then for filter operations, I want to filter on client without further requests.
So I created a binding for tree items with parameter operationMode: 'Client'.
I also have configured in my manifest.json the odata path for my named model "SalesOrder".

The thing is, with operationMode: Client, nothing is fetched initially. In the documentation it says: "The initial request fetches the complete collection".
https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.OperationMode

```
Operations are executed on the client. This only works if all entries are loaded on the client. The initial request fetches the complete collection, filtering and sorting does not trigger further requests.
```

If I remove operationMode Client to default, data is fetched normally. Can someone explain that to me?

```
<Tree
                    id="SC_SO_Tree"
                    growing="true"
                    selectionChange="onSelectionChange"
                    growingScrollToLoad="true"
                    growingDirection="Downwards"
                    mode="MultiSelect"
                    items="{path: 'SalesOrder>/A_SalesOrder',
                                parameters: {
                                    operationMode: 'Client',
                                    expand: 'to_Item',
                                    countMode: 'Inline',
                                    navigation: {
                                        'A_SalesOrder': 'to_Item'
                                    }
                                }
                         
                         }"
                >
```